# Laravel 5: dynamic class name in morphedByMany

Tags: laravel-5

Is this possible in laravel 5?

```
public function attachable($type)
{
    // sample:  $type = 'SomeContent';
    return $this->morphedByMany($type::class, 'message_attachable');
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch
```

edit:

```
[2018-06-17 22:59:13] local.ERROR: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch {"userId":1,"email":"system@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 64): Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch at U:\\www\\prado247\\app\\Models\\Message\\Message.php:25)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the classpath:

```php
public function attachable($type)
{
    // sample:  $type = 'SomeContent';
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\\'.$type, 'message_attachable');
}
```

Comment: Thank you you took your time Jonas, but same err: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch. No matter, there are ways around it

Comment: What's the stacktrace? What's the value of `$type`? How do you call `attachable()`?

Comment: Stacktrace is in edit in Q. $type is a string: SomeContent, which is a name of class. attachable() sits in class Message, which is when used in view, automatically throws this error. So I do not even call that method.

Comment: But you removed the `::class` part (from everywhere)?

Comment: :) nope ... clearly I need to call it quits today - it is 1 am here and my brain is 'stupid' already ... thank you :) works now

Answer (score 0):

Is type meant to be the string name of the class or is it an object of that instance? If it's an instance and you want to know which class it is an instance of you should use

`return $this->morphedByMany(get_class($type),  'message_attachable');`

You can read about the documentation of `get_class` [in the PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) but basically it returns the class of the instance as a string that Eloquent can use.